# mdadm isn't rebuilding the array

Tags: mdadm

I recently replaced a drive (/dev/sdb). All arrays have been rebuilt correctly except for one of them (/dev/md2).
There is no problem with the new drive. Partitions are OK.
mdadm says it's "spare rebuilding" but apparently it isn't happening.

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Oct  8 21:47:44 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1048574840 (1000.00 GiB 1073.74 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1048574840 (1000.00 GiB 1073.74 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Nov 19 00:48:20 2014
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

           Name : rescue:2
           UUID : 3c3c297e:99969855:e5fee8ab:457adcef
         Events : 301

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       2       8       19        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdb3

# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md3 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[2]
      832587071 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[2]
      1048574840 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[2]
      1048574840 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[2] sdb1[3]
      524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not taking any action to rebuild because it's in `auto-read-only` state.

Verify that there's no nasty reason it's gone into that state, **verify that your backups are good before you do anything**, and then set it to writable with `mdadm --readwrite /dev/md2`